# Haskell RSA Example

Tags: haskell, rsa

I'm trying to use `Crypto.Cipher.RSA`, and I'm struggling with encryption and signing. I've looked at the [hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cryptocipher/0.3.0/doc/html/Crypto-Cipher-RSA.html#t:HashASN1).

How should I implement a round-trip example, with both the `encrypt`/`decrypt` and `sign`/`verify` processes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question worries me.  Perhaps I am too familiar with Vincent's work, but I feel that if you understand the operations then using the library would be straight forward or you would at least have very specific questions.  Below, I walk through the two examples you requested and try to stop and explain for each item that might be a "curve ball".

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Crypto.Cipher.RSA
import Crypto.Random.AESCtr
import Crypto.Random
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 (hash)
```

The packages we draw on are: cryptocipher (which you could have mentioned in your question), cprng-aes (for a secure random number generator), crypto-api (an interface to crypto routines, but we'll limit ourselves to just the RNG interface), bytestring, and cryptohash (sign/verify operations are typically parameterizable by hash function).

Now lets encrypt and decrypt a string, then verify this is identity.

```
main = do
    g <- newGenIO :: IO AESRNG
```

The crypto-api interface is used for random number generation.  Because this is an overloaded function we explicitly specify the desired type of random number generator, `AESRNG`.

```
    let Right ((pub,priv),g1) = generate g (512 {- number of bits large -}) (3 {- a prime -})
        msg = "This is my message"
        Right (ct,g2) = encrypt g1 pub msg
```

Generating the key requires the bit size (we used an rather low value for this demo, 512 bits) and any prime over two will do for generation, I just picked 3.

```
    print $ decrypt priv ct
    print $ decrypt priv ct == Right msg
```

The result is as expected:

```
Right "This is my message"
True
```

Signing is not much different, just get a RNG, generate keys, and when you sign be sure to specify the hash function and any meta data you would like to bind.  I selected SHA256 (see the import above) and no metadata (`B.empty`).

```
let Right sig = sign hash B.empty priv msg
print (verify hash B.empty pub msg sig)
```

The result is `Right True`.

I expect most users will make their own functions for some of these operations.

```
mySign q msg = sign hash B.empty q msg
myVerify p msg sig = verify hash B.empty p msg sig
```

Some things I think Vincent and I can do to help people in the future (please suggest additions to this list):

- Not everyone follows the haddock link from `CryptoRandomGen` to the crypto-api and those that do could probably use a pointer to the `cprng-aes` and `drbg` packages.
- Document all functions with examples (examples of poor documentation: The `Integer` value for `generation`? I read the source.  The order of the two `ByteString` values for verify?  I guessed convention and read the source to confirm.)
- Provide a tutorial like this in Vincent's module.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at the benchmarks and tests that come with that package ([browseable source](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-cryptocipher)).